# Can you unwind a type expression in C++11?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Given a type of the form `a<b<c>>` can I unwind it so I get back the typename `a` and `b<c>` then `c`? Or at least be able to have a templated function that allows me to match on elements of a typename, e.g.

```
template <typename C, typename E>
fun(C<E>& h, C<E>& i) {...}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*can I unwind it so I get back the typename `a` and `b<c>` then `c`*" No, because `a` is not a type name. You can trivially get back `b<c>` then `c` though.

Answer (score 4):

```
template <template<typename> class C, typename E>
fun(C<E>& h, C<E>& i) {...}
```

Comment: why doesn't - std::vector<int> v; fun<std::vector, int>(v) - work? whereas template <typename T> class D {}; D<int> d; fun<D,int>(d) works?

Comment: @FredFinkle because vector has form template<typename T, typename Allocator = std::allocator<T>> class vector

it works for example in gcc 4.7+

template <template<typename, typename> class C, typename E, template<typename> class Z>
void fun(C<E, Z<E>>& h, C<E, Z<E>>& i) {}

Comment: This also answers a question I had about how to say "any type" and now I know. Thanks again.

Comment: @FredFinkle `template<typename...> class` will match any kind of template, i.e. variadic or non-variadic.

Comment: @LucDanton Thanks. That idea struck me last night and I've been playing with it this morning. Very helpful